# Fix MongoDB post request giving 401 unauthorised error: null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, mongodb-atlas

I am having an issue with giving a POST request to an API and getting response as 401. Here's the code in next.js 14 with MongoDB atlas:

***libs (Folder)/ mongodb.js (File):***

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connectMongoDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error');
  }
};

export default connectMongoDB;
```

***models (Folder)/ lead.js (File):***

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const leadSchema = new Schema(
  {
    fname: String,
    title: String,
    phone: Number,
    mobile: Number,
    industry: String,
    annualr: Number,
    company: String,
    lname: String,
    email: String,
    street: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    city: String,
    zipcode: Number,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Lead = mongoose.model.Lead || mongoose.model('Lead', leadSchema);

export default Lead;
```

***pages (Root Folder)/ api (Folder)/ leads (Folder)/ createLead.js (File):***

```
import connectMongoDB from "@/libs/mongodb";
import Lead from "@/models/route";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  const {fname, title, phone, mobile, industry, annualr, company, lname, email, street, state, country, city, zipcode} = await req.json();
  await connectMongoDB();

  await Lead.create({fname, title, phone, mobile, industry, annualr, company, lname, email, street, state, country, city, zipcode})

  return NextResponse.json({message: "Lead Created"}, {status: 201})
}
```

I tried many things but it didn't work.

Comment: I strongly doubt this is a MongoDB / MongoDB Atlas issue but rather how you are managing authorization and/or user sessions in nextjs. You should add more details pertaining to that to debug this further

Comment: how can i add more information

Comment: You can update your question with the details.